# how to send checkbox checked value via get in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send checkbox values via `GET`, but the output is always 'on'. Why?
I want to output 'on' if the checkbox is checked; else, output `null`.

My output looks like this:

[demo here](http://careertracker.net/demo/phpajaxsearch/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //show loading bar
    $(".searchBtn").click(function(){
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("enq_search.php?enq=" + encodeURIComponent($("#enq").val()) + "&hosting=" + $("#hosting").val() + "&domain=" + $("#domain").val(),hideLoader());   
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="102">Enquery</td>
        <td width="382">
            <label for="enq"></label>
            <input type="text" name="enq" id="enq" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>checkbox1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hosting" id="hosting" />
            <label for="hosting">hosting</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Checkbox2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="domain" id="domain" />
            <label for="domain">domain</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>    
            <div class="searchBtn">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try put attribute **value** in your **checkboxes**

Comment: @loy your means ?
enq_search.php?enq=" + encodeURIComponent($("#enq").val()) + "&hosting=" + $("#hosting").attribute ??

Comment: hmm..read this: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/

Comment: Thanx 
loy ...
but how can i put this code ?

+ "&hosting=" + $("#hosting").val() .. "val or attribute" ?

Comment: but value is not always "on" or sometimes value is null because of  dynamic check box

Comment: ok..I'll put my answer..just wait..

Comment: There are no checkboxes on your demo page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value<sup>*</sup> of a checkbox that has been ticked is 'on'.  If you want to override that, you have to include the `value` attribute in your input, which you have not done.  For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="domain" id="domain" value="on" />
```

Now, as you are sending the input via an AJAX call whether or not it is checked and simply want to alter the value you send according to its checked property, you will want to change your jQuery to the following:

```
$('.searchBtn').click(function () {
    var url = 'enq_search.php';
    url += '?enq=' + ($('#enq').prop('checked') ? 'on' : 'null');
    url += '&hosting=' + ($('#hosting').prop('checked') ? 'on' : 'null');
    url += '&domain=' + ($('#domain').prop('checked') ? 'on' : 'null');

    $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500).load(url, hideLoader);
});
```

*Actually, to be precise, checkboxes have no default value.  They have an on/off switch state, and values are submitted only when the checkbox is switched on. In the absence of the *required* `value` attribute, most browsers send the switch state (or 'on') as a default value.

Comment: but if check box is unchecked ? or dynamic check then...this code will not work if check box is unchecked

Comment: I didn't notice you weren't using the normal submit process.  Give me a few minutes and I will fix this.

Comment: @Savan, I have updated my answer to fit your needs.  Apologies that I didn't at first understand what you needed.

Comment: @Savan, I've improved it slightly.  Since you will always send either 'on' or 'null', there's no need to check the checkbox's value.  Faster just to send the string 'on' if it's checked.

Comment: BTW, @Savan, my answer will send `enq_search.php?enq=null&hosting=null&domain=null` if checkboxes are not checked, which is how I have interpreted what you need.  If instead you need `enq_search.php?enq=&hosting=&domain=`, just replace `'null'` with `''` in my answer.

Comment: Thank you 
Thhis is very good :) Thank you.....
my get function is now working fine...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="domain" id="domain"  value="ON"/>
```

Comment: but if check box not checked then ...? this is dynamic code i can't fix Value='on'

Comment: if it is not checked then it send null

Comment: default value is always null but if checkbox is not checked then your code show that value="on" ...i want to dynamic some check box can be checked or some unchecked see the demo i already gives with this question

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //show loading bar

    $('#hosting').click(function () {
        var thisCheck = $(this);
        if (thischeck.is(':checked')) {
            thisCheck.val('true');

        } else {
            thisCheck.val('false');
        }
    });

    $(".searchBtn").click(function () {
        $('#sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
        $("#content #sub_cont").load("enq_search.php?enq=" + encodeURIComponent($("#enq").val()) + "&hosting=" + $("#hosting").val() + "&domain=" + $("#domain").val(), hideLoader());
    });
});
```